# How do I programatically add more panes to a avalon dock

Tags: c#, avalondock

I am working with avalon dock v2 and all I am trying to do is have it so when I hit a button it adds another pane to my layout.

This is my existing pane but I don't know the syntax to add another pane to it when I press a button.

```
avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager">
                <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup >
                            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane x:Name="mainDocumentPaneGroup">

                            </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                      </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
                </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
  </avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Here is what I put inside the button.

```
 DockPanel CNPCTab = new DockPanel() { };
        CNPCTab.Name = "CNPCTab";

        mainDocumentPaneGroup.
```

I don't really see any methods that would allow me to add the pane I initialized to group I initialized in the xaml.

Comment: I'd recommend adding some code and explain [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and what issues you're facing.

Comment: I added my code for my existing pane and I am trying to figure out how to add to it when I press a button. Problem is I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if you still need an answer to this or not, but I needed it as well and couldn't really find a good answer anywhere so I'm provding it here.  You need to create a LayoutArchorable, set its Content to your UserControl, and then call the AddToLayout method on the LayoutArchorable to get it to add itself.  In my case I wanted the new window to start as Floating so the user could decide where to drop it, but you still have to assign it somewhere before it can float.

```
    LayoutAnchorable la = new LayoutAnchorable { Title = "New Window", FloatingHeight = 400, FloatingWidth = 500, Content = new YourUserControl() };
    la.AddToLayout(dockingManager, AnchorableShowStrategy.Right);
    la.Float();
```

In this example, I named the DockingManager in the XAML so I could access it from the code behind.

Comment: Thank you, I am still using avalon dock because it has been pretty easy to use and still meets most of my needs. I could never figure out how to do this so I really appreciate it.